# C# Change Font Size Based on Number of Column

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating a windows form for Windows 10 OS on C# which will have difference input by users, and I need to **change the font size** based on the input. I managed to simplify my code for the question as below :

```
 if (input <= 7)
            {
                Font font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            else if(input > 7)
            {
                Font font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 7, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

graphics.DrawString("Hello", font1, Brushes.White, 0, 0, drawFormat);
```

However, I am getting the error *"The name **'font1'** does not exist in current context*" at the *graphics.DrawString()* method. Is there any way I can declare the '**font1**' first and then change the font size later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring font1 inside the if statement, try;

```
 Font font1 = null;
 if (input <= 7)
            {
                font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            else if(input > 7)
            {
                font1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 7, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
if(font1 != null)
    graphics.DrawString("Hello", font1, Brushes.White, 0, 0, drawFormat);
```

Comment: yes. I was looking for a way to declare the font1. This works. Thank you very much!